# Centering shape in Cell increases height from top as row increases

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that is taking information from another sheet and reformating. Every 5th row down there should be an image and all other information is entered correctly in the following rows. As the row number increases it is increasing distance from the top of the cell to the image. For example, if the first shape is 5 pixels from the top of the designated cell, the next will be 6 and so forth. If it was a simple trend I could add a variable to accommodate this, but all images are slightly different in size thus why I am trying to do this dynamically.

So far, as mentioned above, I have tried doing this statically by using a variable to account for the increase, but to no success. Below is the code I am currently using that does not seem to be working.

```
 If CopyPicFromCell(shtSource.Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 2)) Then
    'copied the picture, so paste to shtDest
    shtDest.Paste
    With shtDest.Shapes(shtDest.Shapes.Count)
        .Top = shtDest.Range("A1").Offset(x - 3, 0).Top + ((shtDest.Range("A1").Offset(x - 3, 0).Height - .Height) / 2)
        .Left = shtDest.Range("A1").Offset(x - 3, 0).Left + (shtDest.Range("A1").Offset(x - 3, 0).Width - .Width) / 2
    End With
 End If
```

This always centers the image left to right but does not seem to be doing the trick vertically. Please inform if there is any other information needed. Thanks!

Comment: You have an extra set of brackets in one line. COuld that be the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, just a theory I was testing if the order of operations was not working correctly, but I forgot to delete before posting. Good idea though!